# Boolean Logic Regarding empty arrays.

Tags: javascript, arrays, boolean

quick question:

why does this return false? Just curious.

```
    var myArray = [];
    var myArray1 = new Array();
    console.log(myArray === myArray1)
```

Comment: both are different array... in different location reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two distinct objects are never `===` to one another (nor are they `==`, for that matter). Object equality means that the two objects are really just one object; that is, that both sides of the `===` operator are references to the exact same object.

So, this will give you `true`:

```
var a = [], b = a;
console.log(a === b);
```

Comment: Bro! The stuff wont work even if you do a == check, as they are separate instance. Correct me if am missing something.

Comment: Pointy has said that _"nor are they ==, for that matter"_

Answer (score 0):

Every time you do

- new Array()
  or
- = []

A new instance of the Array constructor is assigned to the variable. So when you do a equality check they aint same. Just as same as when two instance of a class aint same.